# consejo Base de Datos?

Tags: base-de-datos

hola amigos mi problema es el siguiente, quisiera saber cual es la mejor opción para mi siguiente problema?

---

Actualmente en mi base de datos, tengo una tabla que hace referencia a los productos que tengo en una bodega, pero lo que quiero es tener muchas bodegas y no se que opción seria mejor:

1. Tener muchas tablas para diferentes bodegas.
2. Tener pocas tablas pero relacionando los productos y bodegas (creo que genera muchos datos y a futuro seria mas lentas las búsquedas).

oh alguna mejor opción que se les ocurra.

Que opción me sugieren?

Comment: Las respuestas que recibas se basan en opiniones y no suelen tratarse aquí. No obstante, puedo aconsejarte que minimices el número de tablas a usar, sobre todo si van a almacenar información de la misma naturaleza. Relaciona la información almacenada con tus bodegas a modo de relación. Optimizadas y bien indexadas no tienen por que ser lentas y serán modelos mucho más fáciles de mantener (Imagina incluir un nuevo campo si tienes algo así como 100 bodegas con sus 100 tablas... una locura) Es un consejo de alguien que lleva más de 10 años tratando con modelos de datos (y locuras) de todo tipo.

Answer (score 1):

solo necesitas una tabla de `bodegas` 
ejemplo :

```
------------------------
        BODEGAS
------------------------
codigo_bodega 
nombre de bodega
etc...


------------------------
        PRODUCTOS
------------------------
codigo
codigo_bodega
nombre_producto
etc...
```

hacer la relacion en productos con la bodega en `codigo_bodega` en cascada las modificaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque parezca que el modelo "1 tabla por bodega" es más escalable, en realidad conlleva un problema más de fondo.

Con el modelo "1 tabla para muchas bodegas" sólo necesitas un campo adicional "id_bodega", y una tabla de bodegas con su ID. Entre ambas, una llave foránea asegura que no hay registros sin bodega, y que eliminar una bodega elimina sus contenidos.

Con el modelo de muchas tablas, tienes que almacenar en qué tabla va cada bodega. Esto significa que **un campo representa una tabla**. Esa relación de entidades no existe. Sería como hacer un FK al information_schema de la BBDD. **No hay motores de bases de datos en donde puedas hacer esta referencia**, lo que significa que tu base de datos no puede tener integridad referencial entre tus entidades.

Tendrás que escribí tú el código, en tu capa de negocios, para crear y dropear tablas acorde a las inserciones y eliminaciones en la tabla de bodegas, y eso nunca queda tan bien como usar el comportamiento incorporado de un motor relacional.

PD: En el motor PostgreSQL se puede hacer que el campo que contiene el nombre de la tabla de cada bodega cambie si renombras la tabla, usando el tipo de dato `RegClass` pero eso es como toda la ayuda que te va a dar el motor para hacer el schema que estás pensando.